# Magento 2.2.2 .htaccess Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2.2.2

I have uploaded 2.2.2 file on my server and wanted to install it but it gives Internal Server Error.
I have checked the cPanel error.log and found following error log

> [Thu Dec 28 22:35:40.272102 2017] [core:alert] [pid 28738] [client
>   103.38.161.68:41924] /public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command ' < IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Try to give permission 777 to pub/static, generated and app/etc folders using command **sudo chmod -R 777 var pub/static generated app/etc**

Comment: used this command but can't

Comment: i updated original post please check

Comment: Are you using nginx ?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have mod_version installed (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_version.html )

If you cannot install mod_version on your server, you can revert this PR in your local .htaccess Files

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11459/files

but I strongly recommand not doing this, as locally modifying files always makes is nearly impossible to update later! And depending on your setup it should be quite easy to install mod_version.

Comment: i just installed mod_version but still not work

Comment: and my Server Version: Apache/2.4.29

Comment: did you restart apache after installing mod_version?

Comment: can you type in the command "apache2ctl -M" and paste the output here, to make sure, the module is correctly loaded.

Comment: you can also type "a2enmod version" to check if version is enabled (restart apache after this)

Comment: thank you , is work now.. the problem is missing mod_version.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem and it was annoying because there wasn't alot of clear answers or it seemed everyone was using Linux or something else. But i am using Windows 10 latest version as of April 9th, 2018 with Wamp Server (latest version with PHP 7.1 installed). I went to the C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\conf\httpd.conf file and uncommented (removing the # sign) from the LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so line. Hope this works for you and anyone else that stumbles across this.

Comment: it is worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am using wampserver 3.1.9.

1st of all the error is related to "**Apache Server** ". So please review the apache's error log

*My Error log:*

```
{{hostDir}}/magento_cms/.htaccess: Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

For the above error I have enabled an apache module named "**version_module**", which resolved my issue.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks Ramesh.

Answer (score 1):

Make backup of your .htaccess file.

1. Find this lines  and check  them I think you have missing something there.

>

```
       <IfVersion < 2.4>
> 
>             order allow,deny
> 
>             deny from all
> 
>           </IfVersion>
```

2. Or delete htaccess and add one from Magento package
3. Enable mod_version in your apache Somewhere depends from what distribution you use /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf.

Comment: but my file is new download from Magento

Comment: But something goes wrong, try rename this file

Comment: if i delete htaccess is work. But when i upload again is Internal Server Error

Comment: i updated original post please check

Comment: Try to download one from Magento git, maybe it's something wrong with yours. Can you send me this file?

Comment: Ok I added number 3. mod_version

Comment: i just in Magento to download have not edit anything, and where is Magento git? thank you

Comment: i installed mod_version but still not work 
and my Server Version: Apache/2.4.29

Comment: Can you see this module after command: apachectl -M.   Or httpd -M

Comment: thank you , is work now.. the problem is missing mod_version.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_version apache module by un commenting the following line in your apache httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

and you will be good to go